# slideToggle with a negative margin not working as desired

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div where I am using a negative margin on a hidden element which is displayed with `slideToggle()`. However, the negative margin doesn't have an effect on the element until it is completely visible. Is there any way I can get the element to appear with the negative margin already applied? (There's a specific reason I am using a negative margin here that won't be apparent in my code example).

```js
$(function() {
  $('.info').click(function() {
    $('.more-info').slideToggle(500);
  });
});
```

```css
.info {
  height:150px;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.more-info {
  margin-top:-30px;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="info">
  View more +
</div>
<div class="more-info">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce venenatis vehicula venenatis. Nunc at maximus erat. Sed sed vestibulum diam. Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque semper mi nec finibus suscipit. Curabitur ac fringilla orci, vel semper massa. Aenean mattis vel libero ut vulputate. Nunc a vulputate libero. Praesent tristique dictum dictum. In consectetur, nisl in semper lacinia, ligula risus pharetra nisl, sit amet congue felis odio sed dolor. Nullam pharetra varius orci, non dapibus diam dapibus at. Donec felis urna, laoreet id blandit id, vestibulum vulputate eros. Phasellus nunc odio, cursus quis tempor nec, accumsan eu lectus.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Personally, I think your problem looks cooler than the answer, because it slides up from the middle, but whatever.

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb haha, I actually thought the same, unfortunately the client does not :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `translateY()` instead of `margin`

```js
$(function() {
  $('.info').click(function() {
    $('.more-info').slideToggle(500);
  });
});
```

```css
.info {
  height:150px;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.more-info {
  transform: translateY(-30px);
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="info">
  View more +
</div>
<div class="more-info">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce venenatis vehicula venenatis. Nunc at maximus erat. Sed sed vestibulum diam. Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque semper mi nec finibus suscipit. Curabitur ac fringilla orci, vel semper massa. Aenean mattis vel libero ut vulputate. Nunc a vulputate libero. Praesent tristique dictum dictum. In consectetur, nisl in semper lacinia, ligula risus pharetra nisl, sit amet congue felis odio sed dolor. Nullam pharetra varius orci, non dapibus diam dapibus at. Donec felis urna, laoreet id blandit id, vestibulum vulputate eros. Phasellus nunc odio, cursus quis tempor nec, accumsan eu lectus.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the position relative

```js
$(function() {
  $('.info').click(function() {
    $('.more-info').slideToggle(500);
  });
});
```

```css
.info {
  height:150px;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.more-info {
  position:relative;
  top:-30px;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="info">
  View more +
</div>
<div class="more-info">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce venenatis vehicula venenatis. Nunc at maximus erat. Sed sed vestibulum diam. Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque semper mi nec finibus suscipit. Curabitur ac fringilla orci, vel semper massa. Aenean mattis vel libero ut vulputate. Nunc a vulputate libero. Praesent tristique dictum dictum. In consectetur, nisl in semper lacinia, ligula risus pharetra nisl, sit amet congue felis odio sed dolor. Nullam pharetra varius orci, non dapibus diam dapibus at. Donec felis urna, laoreet id blandit id, vestibulum vulputate eros. Phasellus nunc odio, cursus quis tempor nec, accumsan eu lectus.</p>
</div>
```